# Is there anyway to "cast" a CCSprite into a subclass?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have class "Character," which is a subclass of CCSprite. "Character" has only one property, int "extraTag." I am using method getChildByTag:, which returns a CCSprite casted into a CCNode. What I want to do is for it to "cast" it to "Character." I know that casting any class to its subclass is bad practice (and wouldn't work anyway), so I would like to know if it's possible to somehow change the CCSprite to "Character." Function overload doesn't exist in Obj-C, so that's out of the possibilities.

Any help is appreciated; thank you.

PS: If you're wondering why I am subclassing "CCSprite" for one property, it's because I'm using "extraTag" to store when the "CCSprite" is animated. When I call runAction:, it will set "extraTag" to the current action name. I don't want to mess with the existing "tag" property from CCNode, because it's handle by Cocos2D internally for other reasons. If this raises a red flag, let me know; I want to avoid bad practices as much as possible! (:

Comment: So, does your method return an actual object of class `Character`, while its return type is `CCNode`? If so, then a simple cast will do the job.

Comment: The actual object is CCSprite passed as a CCNode; therefore, a simple casting does not work.

Comment: Then you can't magically just make it into your custom class.

Comment: This is exactly what I am asking. Is there someway around this? Assign the "CCSprite" to the new "Character"? It's kind of like how CCArray can use data from a NSArray. I just need to add an instance variable to CCSprite.

Comment: No, there isn't, you can't change the class of an object, no, **no,** ***NO.***

Comment: use the userData property,assign it a class that contains the extra tag and other properties. No need to subclass.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D This is what I'm looking for! I completely forgot about userData! I was so focused with my complex algorithm, I forgot about some simple, basic things. While this solved my personal problem, CRD supplied the answer that directly answered the question. I would love to have both of you as the best answer, but in this case, I have to give it to CRD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly you wish to add a new property to an *existing instance* of a class - hence your idea of defining a subclass and trying to "cast" the wrong way. As has be pointed out you cannot do that.

Wrapping an existing instance in another class which has the desired new property would bind your two things - the property and the instance - together, but as an instance of your wrapper class, which I don't think is what you're after. You *can* use a wrapper to achieve your goal - you define a subclass with both the property and a reference to your existing class, and forward methods to your captured instance (i.e. you build a proxy), but its somewhat involved to do that.

So what does Objective-C offer to help you to your goal?

Objective-C supports *categories* which allow you to add additional methods to an existing class, and hence all instances of an existing class.

But you don't want to add a method, you want to an an `int`. However you can define an `int` *property* - and a property by default is just two methods and some storage (in your case for the `int`). The category gives you the methods, so you just need the storage...

Enter *associated objects*. Objective-C supports associating any number of objects with another object, each associated object is identified by a unique key - effectively Objective-C gives you a dictionary of associated objects. And an object gives you storage...

So in outline you can

a) Declare a class with an `int` property - call it say `MyAddedProperties`

b) Define a category on `CCSprite`, say `MyAddedPropertiesCategory`, too provide your `int` property. Manually implement the setter and getter of this property to lookup and associated instance of `MyAddedProperties` and set/get its `int` property.

You've added a property to an existing class!

(b) requires to create and associate an instance of `MyAddedProperties` on first call of the categories setter/getter and to define a unique key for your associated object. You do the former by looking up your key and if there is no associated object create one. The unique key is any value of type `void *` - i.e. an address. The standard way to obtain a unique key is to declare a `static` variable (of any type, only its address is ever used) in your category and use its address as they key.

You can read about [categories here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) and [associated objects here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418).

It's not a lot of code. If you have trouble writing your solution ask a new question giving your code and what went wrong.

HTH

Comment: This is a very accurate, helpful, and through answer. I solved my problem with the help of LearnCocos2D, but other people who have this question will most likely find this answer the most helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the sprite in the Character class :

```
@interface Character {
    CCSprite *sprite;
    int actionTag;
}

- (void)runAction:(CCAction *)action;

@end
```

and in the implementation file :

```
- (void)runAction:(CCAction *)action{
    actionTag = <action-name>;
    [sprite runAction:action];
}
```

Comment: A good workaround, but isn't this against the IT-HAS AND IT-IS relationship?

Comment: This is just an encapsulation for controlling what is going with the sprite. You can subclass the sprite and add additional properties but from the description it is hard to understand how you are using the Character (subclassed from CCSprite) in the cocos2d context. Can you post relevant code ?

Comment: This is actually better practice than subclassing sprites. It may not be immediately obvious but a game "character" is **not** a sprite. A sprite is a texture rendered to the screen at a specific position, rotation, scale. A character HAS A sprite as its visual representation, but it could also have several, or combine the sprite with particles and labels. A character may even change its visual to label, and then particle explosion. The correct relationship is HAS A not IS A sprite. The latter is also limiting. Try using CCPhysicsSprite with a label and ... uuups!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to elaborate, "Character" is a not  a game character, but a letter as in language. I am trying to add an extra property of CCSprite that came from the character of CCLabelBMFont.